# Paypal IPN is not working with woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, paypal, paypal-ipn

I just tried to setup Paypal-Payment. When purchasing the order is not being processed and getting stuck in the ‘Pending Payment’ status even it has been successfully purchased in paypal. I’ve looked at the wc log and it’s saying ‘Received invalid response from PayPal.

In htaccess i am forcing to https. I somewhere red that https might be an issue, but i didnt get the answer there:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Here is the Log:

```
2020-04-06T22:58:20+00:00 INFO Received invalid response from PayPal IPN
2020-04-06T23:05:38+00:00 INFO Checking IPN response is valid
2020-04-06T23:05:40+00:00 INFO IPN Response: Array
(
    [headers] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object
        (
            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [cache-control] => max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
                    [content-encoding] => gzip
                    [content-type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
                    [paypal-debug-id] => e4c98f0598d92
                    [x-frame-options] => SAMEORIGIN
                    [content-length] => 33
                    [dc] => slc-b-origin-www-2.paypal.com
                    [date] => Mon, 06 Apr 2020 23:05:40 GMT
                    [vary] => Accept-Encoding
                    [set-cookie] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => cwrClyrK4LoCV1fydGbAxiNL6iG=PJUGIfuJg_KNPRMmTBqwlQPVKd6wlywLX0ACxxxSJgwep9Rim9f962iQBfN77mkmh0RIAJzlhtfExKYHyPMSqkJxUEiLM2G9t2jnv97qhVbovwDGM_utWOsWcvpX5rxihyq6W_OfibIik_6ppz8tC-CYr_3Ql1TNJRH5najO9n1b00S5MFxyBJxBLOscMf1EFJ7jl0sxUPUncEy_KRmz9Klaz4_g7w4NKzUHRg_Uk8IoWoOUG1KswPcfg58bODMhnrCGqSsukcMNX7uO9yXroBWIcCGP_7ygIYsmjGadodPPcH9Md6J4n1aZDnulZOmWmKPtOSyT0K5MJfu0Ysi0rwz_luyk_gbIxE3ieOGb-s0vN_aN1t5kNh3NxggHFBKLKVj-fCQ4lVuIBC0IjDwnOWcnc_H4idIfJYIy-17gTlt1EZm3GV6UiSeFjli; Path=/; Domain=paypal.com; HttpOnly; Secure
                            [1] => cookie_check=yes; Path=/; Domain=paypal.com; Expires=Thu, 04 Apr 2030 23:05:40 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
                            [2] => navcmd=_notify-validate; Path=/; Domain=paypal.com; HttpOnly; Secure
                            [3] => navlns=0.0; Path=/; Domain=paypal.com; Expires=Wed, 06 Apr 2022 23:05:40 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
                            [4] => X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DLIVE6.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dappdispatcher%26TIME%3D1586214340%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3Ddcg14.slc; Path=/; Domain=paypal.com; Expires=Mon, 06 Apr 2020 23:35:40 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
                            [5] => X-PP-L7=1; Path=/; Domain=paypal.com; Secure
                            [6] => akavpau_ppsd=1586214940~id=1845e1edd1d3ea70e90442f2f8c7a479; Domain=www.paypal.com; Path=/; Secure; SameSite=None
                        )

                    [strict-transport-security] => max-age=63072000
                )

        )

    [body] => INVALID
    [response] => Array
        (
            [code] => 200
            [message] => OK
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
            [0] => WP_Http_Cookie Object
                (
                    [name] => cwrClyrK4LoCV1fydGbAxiNL6iG
                    [value] => PJUGIfuJg_KNPRMmTBqwlQPVKd6wlywLX0ACxxxSJgwep9Rim9f962iQBfN77mkmh0RIAJzlhtfExKYHyPMSqkJxUEiLM2G9t2jnv97qhVbovwDGM_utWOsWcvpX5rxihyq6W_OfibIik_6ppz8tC-CYr_3Ql1TNJRH5najO9n1b00S5MFxyBJxBLOscMf1EFJ7jl0sxUPUncEy_KRmz9Klaz4_g7w4NKzUHRg_Uk8IoWoOUG1KswPcfg58bODMhnrCGqSsukcMNX7uO9yXroBWIcCGP_7ygIYsmjGadodPPcH9Md6J4n1aZDnulZOmWmKPtOSyT0K5MJfu0Ysi0rwz_luyk_gbIxE3ieOGb-s0vN_aN1t5kNh3NxggHFBKLKVj-fCQ4lVuIBC0IjDwnOWcnc_H4idIfJYIy-17gTlt1EZm3GV6UiSeFjli
                    [expires] => 
                    [path] => /
                    [domain] => paypal.com
                    [host_only] => 
                )

            [1] => WP_Http_Cookie Object
                (
                    [name] => cookie_check
                    [value] => yes
                    [expires] => 1901574340
                    [path] => /
                    [domain] => paypal.com
                    [host_only] => 
                )

            [2] => WP_Http_Cookie Object
                (
                    [name] => navcmd
                    [value] => _notify-validate
                    [expires] => 
                    [path] => /
                    [domain] => paypal.com
                    [host_only] => 
                )

            [3] => WP_Http_Cookie Object
                (
                    [name] => navlns
                    [value] => 0.0
                    [expires] => 1649286340
                    [path] => /
                    [domain] => paypal.com
                    [host_only] => 
                )

            [4] => WP_Http_Cookie Object
                (
                    [name] => X-PP-SILOVER
                    [value] => name=LIVE6.WEB.1&silo_version=880&app=appdispatcher&TIME=1586214340&HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR=dcg14.slc
                    [expires] => 1586216140
                    [path] => /
                    [domain] => paypal.com
                    [host_only] => 
                )

            [5] => WP_Http_Cookie Object
                (
                    [name] => X-PP-L7
                    [value] => 1
                    [expires] => 
                    [path] => /
                    [domain] => paypal.com
                    [host_only] => 
                )

            [6] => WP_Http_Cookie Object
                (
                    [name] => akavpau_ppsd
                    [value] => 1586214940~id=1845e1edd1d3ea70e90442f2f8c7a479
                    [expires] => 
                    [path] => /
                    [domain] => www.paypal.com
                    [host_only] => 
                )

        )

    [filename] => 
    [http_response] => WP_HTTP_Requests_Response Object
        (
            [response:protected] => Requests_Response Object
                (
                    [body] => INVALID
                    [raw] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Paypal-Debug-Id: e4c98f0598d92
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 33
DC: slc-b-origin-www-2.paypal.com
Date: Mon, 06 Apr 2020 23:05:40 GMT
Connection: close
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Set-Cookie: cwrClyrK4LoCV1fydGbAxiNL6iG=PJUGIfuJg_KNPRMmTBqwlQPVKd6wlywLX0ACxxxSJgwep9Rim9f962iQBfN77mkmh0RIAJzlhtfExKYHyPMSqkJxUEiLM2G9t2jnv97qhVbovwDGM_utWOsWcvpX5rxihyq6W_OfibIik_6ppz8tC-CYr_3Ql1TNJRH5najO9n1b00S5MFxyBJxBLOscMf1EFJ7jl0sxUPUncEy_KRmz9Klaz4_g7w4NKzUHRg_Uk8IoWoOUG1KswPcfg58bODMhnrCGqSsukcMNX7uO9yXroBWIcCGP_7ygIYsmjGadodPPcH9Md6J4n1aZDnulZOmWmKPtOSyT0K5MJfu0Ysi0rwz_luyk_gbIxE3ieOGb-s0vN_aN1t5kNh3NxggHFBKLKVj-fCQ4lVuIBC0IjDwnOWcnc_H4idIfJYIy-17gTlt1EZm3GV6UiSeFjli; Path=/; Domain=paypal.com; HttpOnly; Secure
Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; Path=/; Domain=paypal.com; Expires=Thu, 04 Apr 2030 23:05:40 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
Set-Cookie: navcmd=_notify-validate; Path=/; Domain=paypal.com; HttpOnly; Secure
Set-Cookie: navlns=0.0; Path=/; Domain=paypal.com; Expires=Wed, 06 Apr 2022 23:05:40 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DLIVE6.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dappdispatcher%26TIME%3D1586214340%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3Ddcg14.slc; Path=/; Domain=paypal.com; Expires=Mon, 06 Apr 2020 23:35:40 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
Set-Cookie: X-PP-L7=1; Path=/; Domain=paypal.com; Secure
Set-Cookie: akavpau_ppsd=1586214940~id=1845e1edd1d3ea70e90442f2f8c7a479; Domain=www.paypal.com; Path=/; Secure; SameSite=None
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000

INVALID
                    [headers] => Requests_Response_Headers Object
                        (
                            [data:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [cache-control] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
                                        )

                                    [content-encoding] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => gzip
                                        )

                                    [content-type] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
                                        )

                                    [paypal-debug-id] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => e4c98f0598d92
                                        )

                                    [x-frame-options] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => SAMEORIGIN
                                        )

                                    [content-length] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 33
                                        )

                                    [dc] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => slc-b-origin-www-2.paypal.com
                                        )

                                    [date] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Mon, 06 Apr 2020 23:05:40 GMT
                                        )

                                    [vary] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Accept-Encoding
                                        )

                                    [set-cookie] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => cwrClyrK4LoCV1fydGbAxiNL6iG=PJUGIfuJg_KNPRMmTBqwlQPVKd6wlywLX0ACxxxSJgwep9Rim9f962iQBfN77mkmh0RIAJzlhtfExKYHyPMSqkJxUEiLM2G9t2jnv97qhVbovwDGM_utWOsWcvpX5rxihyq6W_OfibIik_6ppz8tC-CYr_3Ql1TNJRH5najO9n1b00S5MFxyBJxBLOscMf1EFJ7jl0sxUPUncEy_KRmz9Klaz4_g7w4NKzUHRg_Uk8IoWoOUG1KswPcfg58bODMhnrCGqSsukcMNX7uO9yXroBWIcCGP_7ygIYsmjGadodPPcH9Md6J4n1aZDnulZOmWmKPtOSyT0K5MJfu0Ysi0rwz_luyk_gbIxE3ieOGb-s0vN_aN1t5kNh3NxggHFBKLKVj-fCQ4lVuIBC0IjDwnOWcnc_H4idIfJYIy-17gTlt1EZm3GV6UiSeFjli; Path=/; Domain=paypal.com; HttpOnly; Secure
                                            [1] => cookie_check=yes; Path=/; Domain=paypal.com; Expires=Thu, 04 Apr 2030 23:05:40 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
                                            [2] => navcmd=_notify-validate; Path=/; Domain=paypal.com; HttpOnly; Secure
                                            [3] => navlns=0.0; Path=/; Domain=paypal.com; Expires=Wed, 06 Apr 2022 23:05:40 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
                                            [4] => X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DLIVE6.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dappdispatcher%26TIME%3D1586214340%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3Ddcg14.slc; Path=/; Domain=paypal.com; Expires=Mon, 06 Apr 2020 23:35:40 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
                                            [5] => X-PP-L7=1; Path=/; Domain=paypal.com; Secure
                                            [6] => akavpau_ppsd=1586214940~id=1845e1edd1d3ea70e90442f2f8c7a479; Domain=www.paypal.com; Path=/; Secure; SameSite=None
                                        )

                                    [strict-transport-security] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => max-age=63072000
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [status_code] => 200
                    [protocol_version] => 1.1
                    [success] => 1
                    [redirects] => 0
                    [url] => https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
                    [history] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [cookies] => Requests_Cookie_Jar Object
                        (
                            [cookies:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [cwrClyrK4LoCV1fydGbAxiNL6iG] => Requests_Cookie Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => cwrClyrK4LoCV1fydGbAxiNL6iG
                                            [value] => PJUGIfuJg_KNPRMmTBqwlQPVKd6wlywLX0ACxxxSJgwep9Rim9f962iQBfN77mkmh0RIAJzlhtfExKYHyPMSqkJxUEiLM2G9t2jnv97qhVbovwDGM_utWOsWcvpX5rxihyq6W_OfibIik_6ppz8tC-CYr_3Ql1TNJRH5najO9n1b00S5MFxyBJxBLOscMf1EFJ7jl0sxUPUncEy_KRmz9Klaz4_g7w4NKzUHRg_Uk8IoWoOUG1KswPcfg58bODMhnrCGqSsukcMNX7uO9yXroBWIcCGP_7ygIYsmjGadodPPcH9Md6J4n1aZDnulZOmWmKPtOSyT0K5MJfu0Ysi0rwz_luyk_gbIxE3ieOGb-s0vN_aN1t5kNh3NxggHFBKLKVj-fCQ4lVuIBC0IjDwnOWcnc_H4idIfJYIy-17gTlt1EZm3GV6UiSeFjli
                                            [attributes] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object
                                                (
                                                    [data:protected] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [path] => /
                                                            [domain] => paypal.com
                                                            [httponly] => 1
                                                            [secure] => 1
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [flags] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [creation] => 1586214340
                                                    [last-access] => 1586214340
                                                    [persistent] => 
                                                    [host-only] => 
                                                )

                                            [reference_time] => 1586214340
                                        )

                                    [cookie_check] => Requests_Cookie Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => cookie_check
                                            [value] => yes
                                            [attributes] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object
                                                (
                                                    [data:protected] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [path] => /
                                                            [domain] => paypal.com
                                                            [expires] => 1901574340
                                                            [httponly] => 1
                                                            [secure] => 1
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [flags] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [creation] => 1586214340
                                                    [last-access] => 1586214340
                                                    [persistent] => 
                                                    [host-only] => 
                                                )

                                            [reference_time] => 1586214340
                                        )

                                    [navcmd] => Requests_Cookie Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => navcmd
                                            [value] => _notify-validate
                                            [attributes] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object
                                                (
                                                    [data:protected] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [path] => /
                                                            [domain] => paypal.com
                                                            [httponly] => 1
                                                            [secure] => 1
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [flags] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [creation] => 1586214340
                                                    [last-access] => 1586214340
                                                    [persistent] => 
                                                    [host-only] => 
                                                )

                                            [reference_time] => 1586214340
                                        )

                                    [navlns] => Requests_Cookie Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => navlns
                                            [value] => 0.0
                                            [attributes] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object
                                                (
                                                    [data:protected] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [path] => /
                                                            [domain] => paypal.com
                                                            [expires] => 1649286340
                                                            [httponly] => 1
                                                            [secure] => 1
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [flags] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [creation] => 1586214340
                                                    [last-access] => 1586214340
                                                    [persistent] => 
                                                    [host-only] => 
                                                )

                                            [reference_time] => 1586214340
                                        )

                                    [X-PP-SILOVER] => Requests_Cookie Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => X-PP-SILOVER
                                            [value] => name%3DLIVE6.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dappdispatcher%26TIME%3D1586214340%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3Ddcg14.slc
                                            [attributes] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object
                                                (
                                                    [data:protected] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [path] => /
                                                            [domain] => paypal.com
                                                            [expires] => 1586216140
                                                            [httponly] => 1
                                                            [secure] => 1
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [flags] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [creation] => 1586214340
                                                    [last-access] => 1586214340
                                                    [persistent] => 
                                                    [host-only] => 
                                                )

                                            [reference_time] => 1586214340
                                        )

                                    [X-PP-L7] => Requests_Cookie Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => X-PP-L7
                                            [value] => 1
                                            [attributes] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object
                                                (
                                                    [data:protected] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [path] => /
                                                            [domain] => paypal.com
                                                            [secure] => 1
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [flags] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [creation] => 1586214340
                                                    [last-access] => 1586214340
                                                    [persistent] => 
                                                    [host-only] => 
                                                )

                                            [reference_time] => 1586214340
                                        )

                                    [akavpau_ppsd] => Requests_Cookie Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => akavpau_ppsd
                                            [value] => 1586214940~id=1845e1edd1d3ea70e90442f2f8c7a479
                                            [attributes] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object
                                                (
                                                    [data:protected] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [domain] => www.paypal.com
                                                            [path] => /
                                                            [secure] => 1
                                                            [samesite] => None
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [flags] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [creation] => 1586214340
                                                    [last-access] => 1586214340
                                                    [persistent] => 
                                                    [host-only] => 
                                                )

                                            [reference_time] => 1586214340
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [filename:protected] => 
            [data] => 
            [headers] => 
            [status] => 
        )

)

2020-04-06T23:05:40+00:00 INFO Received invalid response from PayPal IPN
```

Can someone please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are logging headers/cookies, that is not very useful. You should log the original IPN POST body as received, which should be identical to what you have a record of in your PayPal account at https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history .  And you should at the same time immediately log the GET/POST string of what you *sent* back to PayPal with `cmd=notify-validate` and received the "INVALID" response for.  Then you can set about determining what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you – I will try that one.
I just solved the issue by using another PaypalPlugin for Woocommerce. Not the best way, but at least working so far.